# How to get List webpart in full-width column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-webparts

I want to use Sharepoint Online default webpart called List, to load the default list view on the page.

I want to load it in full-width section but so far I didn't find a way.

Is it possible/and how to do this?

This is basically how it looks like now, and it's not good, list should be taking whole width.. (there is customizer on StatusOfAntrage column, you can ignore it)

[image]

Comment: Are you using team site or communication site?

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP communication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, full width column sections are available only in communication sites and full width column sections only supports the following SharePoint out of the box web parts:

[image]

SharePoint out of the box list web part is not supported in full width column section currently.

---

You can develop custom SharePoint framework (SPFx) web part for full width column web parts - this works for both team and communication sites.

**Documentation**: [SPFx - Use web parts with the full-width column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/basics/use-web-parts-full-width-column)

Comment: Ohh that really sucks! I hope they make it available soon. It's pretty basic thing. Thanks for the info :)

Comment: Yes they should add it for both type of sites and all out of the box web parts.